How do I create a search html page in Google Appscript that connect to a data source in Google Sheets
My google appscript code is experiencing issues. The search function in the back end is successfully outputting "results" but the front end "displayFunction" is not recieving the "results". This results in the search page not working correctly.
I have tried logging the values. The search function in the backend output the data as an array correctly. Meanwhile, the function in the front end is not getting the correct value.
Front end code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search From Google Sheets</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }

      .search-container {
        margin-top: 30px;
      }

      input[type="text"] {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .results {
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .result-item {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      /* Styling for the "Add New Contact" button */
      .add-contact-btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      /* Collapsible details */
      .collapsible {
        display: none;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      }

      .collapsible-content {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Add New Contact button placed before the search bar -->
    <button class="add-contact-btn" onclick="redirectToAddContactPage()">Add New Contact</button>

    <div class="search-container">
      <h1>Search Contacts</h1>
      <!-- Input for real-time search -->
      <input type="text" id="search-query" placeholder="Search for a name..." oninput="handleSearch(event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="results" id="search-results"></div>

    <script>
      // Handle real-time search functionality
      function handleSearch(event) {
        const query = event.target.value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).search(query);
      }

      // Display the search results returned from Apps Script
      function displayResults(results) {
        console.log("results are", results);
  // Ensure results is an array before proceeding
  if (!Array.isArray(results)) {
    results = []; // If results is not an array, treat it as an empty array
  }

  const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('search-results');
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results

  if (results.length > 0) {
    results.forEach(result => {
      const resultItem = document.createElement('div');
      resultItem.classList.add('result-item');

      // Helper function to handle empty or missing values
      const getDisplayValue = value => value ? value : 'N/A';

      // Helper function to format Date objects
      const formatDate = date => {
        if (date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date)) {
          return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
        }
        return 'N/A';
      };

      // Use helper functions for display
      resultItem.innerHTML = `
        <strong>ID Bệnh Nhân:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_benh_nhan)} <br>
        <strong>Họ và Tên:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.name)} <br>
        <button onclick="toggleDetails(event)">Show Details</button>
        <div class="collapsible">
          <div class="collapsible-content">
            <strong>ID Gia Đình:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_gia_dinh)}<br>
            <button onclick="toggleFamilyDetails(event, '${getDisplayValue(result.id_gia_dinh)}')">Show Family Details</button>
            <div class="collapsible" id="family-details-${getDisplayValue(result.id_gia_dinh)}">
              <!-- Family details will be injected here -->
            </div><br>
            <strong>ID Chế Độ Chính Sách:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_che_do_chinh_sach)}<br>
            <strong>ID Lớp Học:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_lop_hoc)}<br>
            <strong>ID Các Hỗ Trợ Của Làng:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_cac_ho_tro_cua_lang)}<br>
            <strong>ID Bệnh Án:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_benh_an)}<br>
            <strong>ID Đánh Giá:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.id_danh_gia)}<br>
            <strong>Ngày Sinh:</strong> ${formatDate(new Date(result.ngay_sinh))}<br>
            <strong>Giới Tính:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.gioi_tinh)}<br>
            <strong>Địa Chỉ Gia Đình:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.dia_chi_gia_dinh)}<br>
            <strong>Số Định Danh Cá Nhân:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.so_dinh_danh_ca_nhan)}<br>
            <strong>Đối Tượng, Thế Hệ Thứ:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.doi_tuong_the_he_thu)}<br>
            <strong>Hộ Khẩu:</strong> ${getDisplayValue(result.ho_khau)}<br>
            <strong>Ngày Tiếp Nhận:</strong> ${formatDate(new Date(result.ngay_tiep_nhan))}<br>
            <strong>Ngày Hòa Nhập:</strong> ${formatDate(new Date(result.ngay_hoa_nhap))}<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;

      resultsDiv.appendChild(resultItem);
    });
  } else {
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>No results found.</p>';
  }
}


      // Toggle the display of the detailed contact information
      function toggleDetails(event) {
        const collapsible = event.target.nextElementSibling;
        if (collapsible.style.display === 'none' || collapsible.style.display === '') {
          collapsible.style.display = 'block';
          event.target.textContent = 'Hide Details';
        } else {
          collapsible.style.display = 'none';
          event.target.textContent = 'Show Details';
        }
      }

      // Toggle family details section based on ID Gia Đình
      function toggleFamilyDetails(event, idGiaDinh) {
        const familyDetailsDiv = document.getElementById(`family-details-${idGiaDinh}`);
        if (familyDetailsDiv.style.display === 'none' || familyDetailsDiv.style.display === '') {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(familyDetails) {
            familyDetailsDiv.innerHTML = `
              <strong>Họ và Tên Bố:</strong> ${familyDetails.father_name}<br>
              <strong>Họ và Tên Mẹ:</strong> ${familyDetails.mother_name}<br>
              <strong>SĐT Liên Hệ:</strong> ${familyDetails.contact_number}<br>
              <strong>Nghề Nghiệp Bố:</strong> ${familyDetails.father_occupation}<br>
              <strong>Nghề Nghiệp Mẹ:</strong> ${familyDetails.mother_occupation}<br>
              <strong>Địa Chỉ:</strong> ${familyDetails.address}<br>
              <strong>Thông Tin Người Giám Hộ:</strong> ${familyDetails.guardian_info}<br>
            `;
            familyDetailsDiv.style.display = 'block';
            event.target.textContent = 'Hide Family Details';
          }).getFamilyDetails(idGiaDinh);
        } else {
          familyDetailsDiv.style.display = 'none';
          event.target.textContent = 'Show Family Details';
        }
      }

      // Redirects the user to the "Add/Edit Contact" page
      function redirectToAddContactPage() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
          document.open();
          document.write(html);
          document.close();
        }).getedit_contacts();
      }

      // Initial load of all contacts when the page loads
      window.onload = function() {
        loadAllContacts();
      };

      function loadAllContacts() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).getAllContacts();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Backend code
// This function fetches all contacts, including additional fields
function getAllContacts() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Bệnh nhân'); // Ensure correct sheet name
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from the sheet (including headers)
  
  const contacts = [];
  
  // Loop through all rows (skipping the header row)
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const contact = {
      id_benh_nhan: data[i][0] || 'N/A', // ID bệnh nhân (use 'N/A' if empty)
      id_gia_dinh: data[i][1] || 'N/A', // ID gia đình
      id_che_do_chinh_sach: data[i][2] || 'N/A', // ID chế độ chính sách
      id_lop_hoc: data[i][3] || 'N/A', // ID lớp học
      id_cac_ho_tro_cua_lang: data[i][4] || 'N/A', // ID các hỗ trợ của làng
      id_benh_an: data[i][5] || 'N/A', // ID bệnh án
      id_danh_gia: data[i][6] || 'N/A', // ID đánh giá
      name: data[i][7] || 'N/A', // Họ và tên
      ngay_sinh: data[i][8] || 'N/A', // Ngày sinh
      gioi_tinh: data[i][9] || 'N/A', // Giới tính
      dia_chi_gia_dinh: data[i][10] || 'N/A', // Địa chỉ gia đình
      so_dinh_danh_ca_nhan: data[i][11] || 'N/A', // Số định danh cá nhân
      doi_tuong_the_he_thu: data[i][12] || 'N/A', // Đối tượng, thế hệ thứ
      ho_khau: data[i][13] || 'N/A', // Hộ khẩu
      ngay_tiep_nhan: data[i][14] || 'N/A', // Ngày tiếp nhận
      ngay_hoa_nhap: data[i][15] || 'N/A' // Ngày hòa nhập
    };
    contacts.push(contact);
  }

  // Return all contacts
  return contacts;
}


// This function performs the search operation
function search(query) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Bệnh nhân'); // Change 'Bệnh nhân' to your actual sheet name
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from the sheet (including headers)
  
  const results = [];
  
  // Ensure query is a string and convert to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
  const searchQuery = (query && query.toString().toLowerCase()) || ''; // Handle query if undefined or null
  
  // Loop through the rows in the sheet starting from the second row (skipping the header row)
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Ensure the name field (data[i][7]) exists and is a string before calling .toString()
    const name = (data[i][7] && data[i][7].toString().toLowerCase()) || ''; // If name is undefined or null, use an empty string

    // If the name contains the search query (case-insensitive), add the result to the 'results' array
    if (name.includes(searchQuery)) {
      const result = {
        id_benh_nhan: data[i][0],
        id_gia_dinh: data[i][1],
        id_che_do_chinh_sach: data[i][2],
        id_lop_hoc: data[i][3],
        id_cac_ho_tro_cua_lang: data[i][4],
        id_benh_an: data[i][5],
        id_danh_gia: data[i][6],
        name: data[i][7],
        ngay_sinh: data[i][8],
        gioi_tinh: data[i][9],
        dia_chi_gia_dinh: data[i][10],
        so_dinh_danh_ca_nhan: data[i][11],
        doi_tuong_the_he_thu: data[i][12],
        ho_khau: data[i][13],
        ngay_tiep_nhan: data[i][14],
        ngay_hoa_nhap: data[i][15]
      };
      results.push(result); // Add the matching result
    }
  }

  // Return the results array to the front-end (HTML page)
  Logger.log(results);
  return results;
}


// This function fetches the family details for a given ID Gia Đình
function getFamilyDetails(idGiaDinh) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Gia đình'); // Ensure correct sheet name
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from the sheet (including headers)
  
  let familyDetails = {
    father_name: 'N/A',  // Default values in case data is missing
    mother_name: 'N/A', 
    contact_number: 'N/A',
    father_occupation: 'N/A',
    mother_occupation: 'N/A',
    address: 'N/A',
    guardian_info: 'N/A'
  };

  // Loop through the rows in the "Gia Đình" sheet and find the matching ID Gia Đình
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const familyId = data[i][0]; // Assuming ID Gia Đình is in the first column
    if (familyId == idGiaDinh) {
      familyDetails = {
        father_name: data[i][1] || 'N/A',  // Họ và tên bố
        mother_name: data[i][2] || 'N/A',  // Họ và tên mẹ
        contact_number: data[i][3] || 'N/A',  // SĐT liên hệ
        father_occupation: data[i][4] || 'N/A',  // Nghề nghiệp bố
        mother_occupation: data[i][5] || 'N/A',  // Nghề nghiệp mẹ
        address: data[i][6] || 'N/A',  // Địa chỉ
        guardian_info: data[i][7] || 'N/A'  // Thông tin người giám hộ
      };
      break;
    }
  }

  return familyDetails;
}


    


Make sure you're not sending illegal parameters. For eg, Dates are illegal.

Can you share a sample spreadsheet with the script you're using so I can fully understand how your code works? It will also be easier to test.

The question title is too broad. You are asking how to fix a specific part of your code, the oninput event of the input element and the function called by this event. Please add a [mcve] focused on this part, i.e., the style tag, among other parts, is not required.
